# Conda command not found despite updating PATH variable

Tags: conda

I installed Anaconda.

The following path has been added to the PATH variable and it is in the .bashrc file

```
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
```

Yet, the "conda" command is not working. What else could be wrong?

Comment: It is not a common case but what happened was that I changed the username of my account earlier and the paths that included my old username were outdated.